# Move a file after completion by youtube-dl

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, youtube-dl

I want "youtube-dl" to download a video from youtube. and move to a new folder:
From youtube-dl Documentation:

```
--exec CMD                       Execute a command on the file after
                                 downloading, similar to find's -exec
                                 syntax. Example: --exec 'adb push {}
                                 /sdcard/Music/ && rm {}'
```

I want to include it in a python script in Rasbian on my Raspberry Pi, and to move a file, I have to specify the "old file" like this:

```
shutil.move("path/to/current/movie.mp4", "path/to/new/location/movie.mp4")
```

How do I make a "reference" to the file or how can this be done?

**EDIT:**

phihag mentioned it is possible to keep the original name, this actually looks like working, but the file is not created anywhere and the /Python/done/ folder is empty.
This is -o in general i cant get working.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Python/done $ sudo youtube-dl --o '/Python/done/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KA3Q1duzwaE
[youtube] KA3Q1duzwaE: Downloading webpage
[youtube] KA3Q1duzwaE: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] KA3Q1duzwaE: Extracting video information
[download] Destination: /Python/done/Matre Gims - Tu vas me manquer (Clip Officiel)-KA3Q1duzwaE.f248.webm
[download] 100% of 34.98MiB in 00:12
[download] Destination: /Python/done/Matre Gims - Tu vas me manquer (Clip Officiel)-KA3Q1duzwaE.f251.webm
[download] 100% of 4.06MiB in 00:01
[ffmpeg] Merging formats into "/Python/done/Matre Gims - Tu vas me manquer (Clip Officiel)-KA3Q1duzwaE.webm"
Deleting original file /Python/done/Matre Gims - Tu vas me manquer (Clip Officiel)-KA3Q1duzwaE.f248.webm (pass -k to keep)
Deleting original file /Python/done/Matre Gims - Tu vas me manquer (Clip Officiel)-KA3Q1duzwaE.f251.webm (pass -k to keep)
pi@raspberrypi ~/Python/done $ dir
```

Though if i try again, im told its already downloaded

```
WARNING: Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv.
[download] /Python/done/test4.mkv.mkv has already been downloaded and merged
```

Is the syntax wrong?

Comment: wild guess: `mv {} /path/to/movie.mp4`

Comment: Why don't you download the movie at the correct directory in the first place using `-o?`?

Comment: I tried this:
youtube-dl --exec 'mv {} /Python/done/movie.mp4' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TpyRE_juyA

But it dosnt work and i can see this:
File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/postprocessor/execafterdownload.py", line 23, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings

Comment: I want to maintain the original name, which is impossible with "-o", but I guess its also impossible with moving the file as well

Comment: @Yoshidk What do you mean by *maintain*? Is the desired result two files?  What's wrong with `-o '/Python/done/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s'`?

Comment: @phihag with using --recode , you will temporarily have multiple media files in the output location. This will cause invalid results with applications that scan for new/changed media files like Plex Media Server and Jellyfin. it will add the temp media fiel to the library, only to later error on the non-existent file. It's better to only output the final/permanent file to the output folder.